# Access query if blank run another query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to run an Access Report in which the value of a field depends on a query. I have a subreport for this.

If the value is not found in the first query it must run another until the value is found. How can I accomplish this in Access 2003 +. Is doing this in VBA using DAO or ADO the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to `UNION ALL` your queries and use ordering to pick the first found value (assuming you are talking about a reasonable and finite number of queries).  For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MyVal
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Seq, Field1 AS MyVal FROM MyQuery1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS Seq, Field1 AS MyVal FROM MyQuery2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 AS Seq, Field7 AS MyVal FROM MyQuery3)
ORDER BY Seq, MyVal
```